# i'm new to preg_split and regex, am I doing this right?

Tags: php

```
function(){
return preg_split('/[-]/', $_COOKIE[$cookie_login]);
}
```

I have this being returned, $_COOKIE[$cookie_login] is "1-blahblahblah"

yet when I try to retrieve this using the function above like so:

```
$string = function();
```

I get empty strings, such as `$string[0]` and `$string[1]` are both empty, what am I doing wrong?

i'm trying to figure out how to use preg_split just like I used the old split since i'm changing to php 5.4

Edit: here is the full function:

```
    function get_session(){
    global $cookie_login;
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_login])){
        return preg_split('/[-]/', $_COOKIE[$cookie_login]);
    }
}
```

and

```
$string = get_session();
```

`$string[0]` is empty as well as `$string[1]`, but `print_r($string)` works.

Comment: Do you really need a regex here?  Why not just `explode('-', $_COOKIE[$cookie_login]);`?  P.S. Your code works fine: http://ideone.com/fCLo6M

Comment: Avoid using regex when you have something better available like @RocketHazmat said

Comment: So, "print_r($string) works"?  What does it print?  P.S. Your regex is fine: http://ideone.com/aJVrvO

Answer (score 3):

You're using `$cookie_login` within the function, but that variable's not defined anywhere. Perhaps it should be just

```
$_COOKIE['cookie_login']
```

instead?

As well, `[-]` in a regex is the same as just `-`. This isn't "wrong", it's just somewhat redundant to specify a character class for a single character.

---

followup: Ok, now that you've posted more, here's a major change you could do

**DON'T USE GLOBALS** You're already got a function, so pass in the cookie name as a paramter:

```
function get_sesssion($name) {
   return preg_split('/-/', $_COOKIE[$name]);
}
$sess = get_session('cookie_login');
```

Comment: AH!  Yeah, that's probably his issue.  `$cookie_login` is undefined inside his function.

Comment: nah, i have global $cookie_login; set, it's just a string

Comment: @user1925957: Just because it's global doesn't mean the function can read it.  How are you calling that function?  You might need to add `global $cookie_login;` to it.  Or pass `$cookie_login` as a parameter.  Try to `var_dump($cookie_login);` inside your function, just to be sure.

Comment: global $cookie_login has to be executed inside of the function

Comment: `global` executed outside of the function will not magically turn the specified variable(s) into a superglobal. You have to declare the variable global **WITHIN** the function. e.g. `func x() { global $foo; }`. `global $foo; function x() { $foo }` is not going to work. $foo inside the function will STILL be undefined.

Comment: ok I guess I shoulda showed you guys the entire function to not add confusion:

Comment: function get_session(){
 global $cookie_login;
 if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_login])){
  return preg_split('/[-]/', $_COOKIE[$cookie_login]);
 }
    }

Comment: don't post entire chunks of code in a comment. it's unreadable. edit your question and post it there.

Comment: Please don't use global :s

Answer (score 1):

```
function(){
  return explode('-', $_COOKIE[$cookie_login]);
}
```

Comment: Your idea of using explode instead of expreg is interesting, but you missed the point of the local variable non defined ;) +1 though for the explode though

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset` to check that cookie exists, i assumes that its `cookie_login` instead of `$cookie_login`, or its really `$cookie_login`, try using `global $cookie_login` inside your function, or pass it as a function `argument` (thats better choice than setting global)

```
<?php
  function get_session() {
    global $cookie_login;
    if ( $cookie_login && isset( $_COOKIE[$cookie_login] ) ) {
      return explode( "-", $_COOKIE[$cookie_login] );
    }
    return false;
  }

  $string = get_session( 'some_cookie' );
  var_dump( $string );
?>
```

or as a function `argument`

```
<?php
  function get_session( $cookie_login = null ) {
    if ( $cookie_login && isset( $_COOKIE[$cookie_login] ) ) {
      return explode( "-", $_COOKIE[$cookie_login] );
    }
    return false;
  }
?>
```

when doing `var_dump` if you got `bool(false)` that means that cookie is not set, otherwise you will get at least an array :\

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_split('/[-]/', $_COOKIE[$cookie_login]);
```

As `-` is a special `RegEx character`, consider escaping it like this `\\-`.

```
preg_split('~[\\-]~', $_COOKIE[$cookie_login]);
```

^ I use `~` as a wrapper character for `RegEx patterns` as `/` is too widely used in **HTML/XML**.